# how to associate vibration with a button click

Tags: objective-c

Hi 
    I my app there is a button with which i want to associate vibration.Can some one tell me the code to be put into the method associated with the button.Thanks.

Comment: Accept some answers to your other questions, then you can expect new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Don't forget to import AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h

Comment: Note Vibration dosent works in ipod(feature is not given. ) VISIT   http://www.macrumors.com/2010/09/08/fourth-generation-ipod-touch-does-have-vibration/

Answer (score 1):

We need to put the line

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

in a different method then call the method in the method corresponding to the button.